# C# Error does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have the following type of method in one class in my stack:

```
public void CalculateNewDate(DateTime newDate)
    {
      //datetimecalculations
    }
```

I am trying to call the method from a different class in the stack, and pass in a newDate parameter to get the results of the datetimecalculations.

In the new class within the project, I am calling it like this:

```
Public void methodName(param,param)
{ foreach loop(param)
    {If item != null)
     DateTime newDate = item.Date.value;
      {
        item.item.date = CalculateNewDate(newDate);
      }
    }
}
```

I am getting the "The name "CalculateNewDate" does not exist in the current context" error message with an option to generate a method stub.

I do have the correct usings in place for namespace. Any idea why I can not call this method from my other class?

Sorry I can not be much more specific than that due to restrictions on what we post publically.

Comment: You're trying to call a method in another class like it is a static method, but it isn't. You have to create an instance of that class and call the method that way.

Comment: maybe you can also post sample code without syntax errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# is an object oriented Language and the main building block is the class.
You can't call a method defined inside a class without creating an instance of that class.
(Unless you declare the method static, but this is not really the matter here)

So suppose you have this class

```
public class AClassOfMine
{
    public DateTime CalculateNewDate(DateTime newDate)
    {
      //datetimecalculations
      return calculatedDate;
    }
}
```

if you want to use that method you need an instance of that class

```
public void methodName(param,param)
{ 
    foreach loop(param)
    {
        If (item != null)
        {
            DateTime newDate = item.Date.value;
            AClassOfMine anInstance = new AClassOfMine();
            item.item.date = anInstance.CalculateNewDate(newDate);
        }
    }
}
```

of course the method `CalculateNewDate` is supposed to return a new date so your method signature should be changed accordingly. (Return a date)

Comment: Thank you, I actually do have an instance of the class available, I wasnt explictly declaring it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You have and **instance** available but you haven't declared it? Could you show the relative code?

Comment: classname.methodname(param). I had forgot to put the classname in the call as shown above. Once I added it, problem was resolved. Thanks