# Object doesn't exist in current context?

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a project with three classes, but after I have created them and try to call upon them I am told they do not exist in current context.

```cs
if(p2 == 1)
{
    Hamburgler playerTwo = new Hamburgler(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Hamburgler Chosen!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else if(p2 == 2)
{
    Ronald playerTwo = new Ronald(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Ronald McDonald Chosen!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else if (p2 ==3)
{
    Kids playerTwo = new Kids(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Fry Kids Chosen!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else 
{
    Hamburgler playerTwo = new Hamburgler(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Defaulting as Hamburgler");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

while (playerOne.Health > 0 || playerTwo.Health > 0)
{
    int atk1 = playerOne.Fight();
    playerTwo.Health = playerTwo.Health - atk1;
    int atk2 = playerTwo.Fight();
    playerOne.Health = playerOne.Health - atk2;
}
```

Here is the sequence of code where I create `playerTwo` (`playerOne` is created right above) and then I try to call them to start the "fight". Any help is appreciated and I am sorry if this question is poorly presented I am new to all of this.

Error CS0103

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Error does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787899/c-sharp-error-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Can you show these 3 classes pls?

Comment: You are declaring 4 playerTwo variables in the if-else { ... } blocks. They 'live' only within those blocks and are unknown outside of them. So you will need to move out the declaration in front of your if statement and only assign the values in the { ... } blocks. That also mean, that your `Hamburgler`, `Ronald` and `Kids` classes must have a common base class with a method `Fight`.

Answer (score 2):

Each if, else if, else and while has it's own block-level scope inside the brackets and you are declaring `playerTwo` inside each of their scopes, thus making it non-visible outside their scopes.

What that means is that what you declare inside the brackets of the if will be visible only inside those set of brackets. Same goes for EACH else, else if, while.

One way to fix this is create a base class and inherit each of your `Hamburgler`, `Ronald` and `Kids` class from it.

Here's an example of how the base class could look like using the members and methods you have provided:

```
class Character {
    public Character() { }
    
    public virtual void Fight() {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.Name} is fighting");
    }

    public string Name;
    public int PlayerId;
    public int Health;
}
```

Afterwards, just create each of your classes inheriting from the `Character` class as such:

```
class Hamburgler: Character { }
class Ronald: Character { }
class Kids: Character { }
```

Now, if you were not satisfied with the Attack function just printing that specific text, you can override it for each class as such:

```
class Hamburgler: Character {
    public void Attack() {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.Name} the Hamburgler is fighting");
    }
}
```

Finally, your previous code should look like this:

```
Character playerTwo;
if(p2 == 1)
{
    playerTwo = new Hamburgler(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Hamburgler Chosen!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else if(p2 == 2)
{
    playerTwo = new Ronald(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Ronald McDonald Chosen!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else if (p2 ==3)
{
    playerTwo = new Kids(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Fry Kids Chosen!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else 
{
    playerTwo = new Hamburgler(){Name = name, PlayerId = playerCount, Health = 100};
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Defaulting as Hamburgler");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

while (playerOne.Health > 0 || playerTwo.Health > 0)
{
    int atk1 = playerOne.Fight();
    playerTwo.Health = playerTwo.Health - atk1;
    int atk2 = playerTwo.Fight();
    playerOne.Health = playerOne.Health - atk2;
}
```

If you want to take this approach I recommend you to read about [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance) as there are some caveats to it.